# Is it possible to omit FieldID in struct when using gorm?

Tags: mysql, sql, go, orm, go-gorm

Looking at an [example from their documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html):

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company
}

type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}
```

`CompanyID` field seems rather redundant. Is it possible to get rid of it using some tags on `Company` field instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `User` definition like this did the trick:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name    string
  Company Company `gorm:"column:company_id"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `BaseModel` instead of using `gorm.Model`, for example

```
type BaseModel struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"not null;AUTO_INCREMENT;primary_key;"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time
    UpdatedAt *time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index"`
}
```

Then, in the `User`, do something like this, basically overriding the default `Foreign Key`

```
type User struct {
    BaseModel
    Name    string
    Company company `gorm:"foreignKey:id"`
}
```

And the Company

```
type Company struct {
  BaseModel
  Name string
}
```